# Print statements in a for loop

Tags: python

I am working on a function  which takes a positive integer `N` and computes the following sum:

```
1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 + .... N.
```

My professor said we can not use "math formulas" on this, so how could I go about it?

I thought about using a `for` loop, but I don't know how or what to write for the `print` statement. This is what I have so far:

```
n=int(input("enter N="))
for i in range(1, n+1, 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        # I'm not sure what print statement to write here
```

I tried `print(i= "+" i+1)` and just weird stuff like that, but I get errors and am lost after that.

what i have now

```
n=int(input('enter N='))
total=0
print("sum",)
for i in range(1, n+1, 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        count=count - i
        print("-", i)
    else:
        count=count + i
        print("+", i, end=" ")
print("=", total)

#still get errors saying name count not defined and unsupported sperand for +:
```

Comment: By "not use math formulas" I think he means you can't use any of the well-known shortcuts; you still have to do basic arithmetic to calculate the total along the way, right?

Comment: "You are not allowed to use a math formula (like my_sum = (N*(N+1))/2 ) to compute this sum. It should be computed by adding and subtracing all the values. " thats what my professor made clear.

Comment: You already have several answers.  Some give hints, the others just give you the answer.  It's up to you how much you want to struggle with it yourself. ;)

Comment: @John haha im new with this programming stuff so even if the answer is right infront of me i will still most likely suffer until i fully understand it

Comment: OK, I think the various answers below are what your professor is asking for. (As a side note, you might want to try implementing the `N*(N+1)/2` trick too, both for practice, and so you can compare the results between the two and make sure they match.)

Comment: @abarnert, thanks you have been very helpful. i will see if i can get close to what im looking for

Comment: @hayden: Yes, it's left as an exercise to the reader to figure out how to apply the `N*(N+1)/2` trick for alternating signs. (Or find the simpler rule.) I'm sure you can find all those answers just by looking up "1 - 2 + 3 - 4" on Wikipedia, so it's not much of an exercise…

Comment: @hayden: Well, you get a gold star anyway, but let some of the other students answer. :)

Comment: The reason your new version gets errors is that you're initializing a variable called `total`, then using a variable called `count`. Use one name or the other. But also, you need to add the `, end=" "` part to the first two print statements, not just the third.

Comment: @abarnert you were right, i changed all of them to count and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to accumulate the sum as described, and to do it by looping instead of "using math formulas", you want to do this:

```
n=int(input("enter N="))
total = 0
for i in range(1, n+1, 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        ????
    else:
        ????
print(total)
```

You should be able to figure out what the ???? are: you need to do something to total for each i, and it's different for even and odd.

Now, if you want it to print out something like this:

> sum 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 + .... N = X

You can print things out along the way like this:

```
n=int(input("enter N="))
total = 0
print ("sum", end=" ")
for i in range(1, n+1, 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print("-", i, end=" ")
        ????
    else:
        if i == 1:
           print(i, end=" ")
        else:
           print("+", i, end=" ")
        ????
print("=", total)
```

If you want to keep negative and positive totals separately and then add them, as you mentioned in an edit, change `total = 0` to `ntotal, ptotal = 0, 0`, then change each of the ???? parts so one works on one total, one on the other.

All of the above is for Python 3. If you want to run it in Python 2, you need to turn those `print` function calls into `print` statements. For the simple cases where we use the default newline ending, that's just a matter of removing the parentheses. But when we're using the `end=" "`, Python 2's `print` statement doesn't take keyword parameters like that, so you instead have to use the "magic comma", which means to end the printout with a space instead of a newline. So, for example, instead of this:

```
print("+", i, end=" ")
```

You'd do this:

```
print "+", i,
```

Again, for Python 3, you don't have to worry about that. (Also, there are ways to make the exact same code run in both Python 2 and 3—e.g., use `sys.stdout.write`—which you may want to read up on if you're using both languages frequently.)

Comment: @sshekhar: There are no built-in functions named `i`, `n`, or `total`, and those are the only variables I'm using. So you think wrong.

Comment: sorry i got you wrong, i didn't see i was using sum as a variable. Thanks for guiding me in right direction.

Comment: in the second part, where we have print "+", i i get errors in my code saying its unsupported. why is that?

Comment: Ah, you're using Python 3.2.3. The syntax for printing has changed between 2.x (which most people use) and 3.x (which is the current version). I'll change my answer.

Comment: oh okay maybe thats why my things are a bit off

Comment: If you have trouble converting the rest of the print statements to Python 3 (everything else should work the same), let me know. (Really, in Python, you want to avoid this style of printing anyway, and Python 3 just gives you more reason to avoid it. But for simple quick&dirty cases it's often very useful, and it's worth learning how to translate prints between Python 2 and 3.)

Comment: i keep getting errors, maybe i put in the wrong thing where you put the ???? but i will repost what i have so far

Comment: You got the ???? parts right, but not the print statements. Let me rewrite it for Python 3 first, with notes about Python 2, instead of vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there already. I'm not sure why you think you need to put a print statement inside the loop, though. You only want one result, right? You already have if i % 2 == 0 - which is the case where it's even - and you want to either add or subtract based on whether the current i is odd or even. So keep a running tally, add or subtract in each loop iteration as appropriate, and print the tally at the end.

Comment: i want something like this eventually, but im trying to work on it part by part Sample run:
Enter N: 4
1 - 2 + 3 - 4 = -2
The positive sum is: 4
The negative sum is: 6

Comment: @atmatm: Then you can just keep two `total`s instead of one. For even numbers, add to `negativetotal`, for odd numbers, add to `positivetotal`.

Answer (score 1):

You see the difference between what happens with odd and even numbers, which is good.

So, as you cycle through the list, **if** the number is even, you do one operation, or **else** you do another operation.

After you've computed your result, then you print it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of explanations in the answers already here. So I will try to address the different ways in which you can compute this sum:

**Method 1**:

```
def mySum(N):
    answer = 0
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        if i%2:
            answer += i
        else:
            answer -= i
    return answer
```

**Method 2**:

```
def mySum(N):
    answer = 0
    for i in range(1, N+1, 2):
        answer += i
    for i in range(2, N+1, 2):
        answer -= i
    return answer
```

**Method 3**:

```
def mySum(N):
    pos = range(1, N+1, 2)
    neg = range(2, N+1, 2)
    return sum(pos) - sum(neg)
```

**Method 4**:

```
def mySum(N):
    return sum([a-b for a,b in zip(range(1, N+1, 2), zip(2, N+1, 2))])
```

**Method 5**:

```
def mySum(N):
    return sum([i*-1 if not i%2 else i for i in range(1,N+1)])
```

**Method 6**:

```
def mySum(N):
    return sum(map(lambda n: n*[-1, 1][i%2], range(1, N+1)))
```

Again, these are only to help prime you into python. Others have provided good explanations, which this is not meant to be

Answer (score -2):

```
count = 0
print "0"
for i in range(1, n+1, 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        count = count - i
        print "-" , i
    else:
        count = count + i
        print "+" , i
print "=", count
```

Comment: Nope. This will always print n+1, not the total. Also, your later edit to print as it goes along doesn't print what the OP asked for, so I'm not sure why you added it. (Have you actually run it to see what it prints?)

Comment: Hint: do you really want to print n+2 lines of output?

Comment: @abarnert just accidentally put `i` instead of `count`. What does my latest edit do that isn't what the OP wanted? Looks good to me.

Comment: @abarnert Quick solution. I was assuming the OP was more interested in the numbers than the format. I just didn't feel like spending more time than I needed to, and I don't really speak python.

Comment: @atmatm It works fine -- it's tested. You're probably using a later version, which replaces `print x` with `print(x)`

Comment: @atmatm oh-- you're the OP, lol. So I guess it's not a versioning issue. I dunno - works fine for me.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Given that other people have already written working answers, why do you feel the need to write one at all when you don't speak Python?

Comment: @abarnert When I started writing my answer, there were no answers here. Given that my answer works just fine, I think that's ok. Why do *you* feel the need to invalidate and discredit other people's work?

Comment: It's not that I have "a need to invalidate and discredit other people's work" but that I believe in voting according to the guidelines of the site. If someone posts sample code that does the wrong thing, with no explanation, you downvote it and explain why. If you recognize that your answer is useless, you fix it or withdraw it, you don't whine at the people who downvoted it. That's how the site works.

Comment: @abarnert I never even used the word downvote. I was referring to you posting 100 nitpicky, useless comments. Also, my answer isn't useless, nor does it do "the wrong thing". It does *exactly* what the OP asked for.

Comment: If you think pointing out that your answer always prints the wrong value is a "nitpicky, useless" comment, I really don't know what to say.

Comment: @abarnert Dang, man, this is like talking to a wall. *That* comment was just fine. It helped me find what was unquestionably a typo and fix it. Your comments after that one were the nitpicky ones.

Comment: Your version still prints n+2 lines of output, where the OP's description prints 1 line. Everyone else's version gets this right. My only comment was a hint to help you fix this, which you just answered defensively by saying that you "don't really speak python". If you can find the hundreds of other comments on your post that are invisible to everyone else, let me know; otherwise, I'm done talking to you.

Comment: @abarnert nowhere in the question does it say anything about how many lines of output he wants. If you can find invisible verbage that says how many he does, let me know; otherwise, I'll just keep my answer the way it is.